# can't post to physics SO

Tags: bug, status-completed

there seems to be a problem going on with the site, list of questions are not being updated, and some of them are dissapearing, like this one:

[Does positronium have a stable crystalline phase?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37516/does-positronium-have-a-stable-crystalline-phase)

Answer (score 2):

This was a side-effect of our database migration. We had to rebuild a few services after it, so things were down for a while.

Should be all good now!

Answer (score 0):

There is some maintanance of the Stack Exchange servers going on. There were notices on the sites for a while. Presumably everything hasn't gone perfectly smoothly.